# Relativistic rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, curvature, rotation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Consider the following two scenarios:

a) A particle is rotating in the $x-y$ plane about some point fixed in lab frame at a radius $a$ with relativistic angular speed $\omega$. **Do not include** the stress-energy of whatever forces keep them in orbit.

b) A particle is rotating in the $x-y$ plane about some point fixed in lab frame at a radius $a$ with relativistic angular speed $\omega$. **Include** the stress-energy of whatever forces keep them in orbit.

For both scenarios, I would like to calculate the nonzero components of stress-energy tensor in *cylindrical coordinates*. My question is this: **Will the stress energy tensor be same or different?**

I think it will be different because problem (a) does not include accelerated frame which leads to curvilinear coordinate (hence the metric tensor changes), while problem two includes force. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'including' or 'not including' the forces which keep them in orbit?

Comment: This question is based on problem 4.21(b) "A First Course in General Relativity " by Bernard F. Schutz . They have used " Do not include the stress–energy of whatever forces keep them in orbit." I guess you should neglect such forces from the stress energy tensor

Comment: Have you tried looking at Kirk McDonald's physics examples at http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/?  One that may be of tangential interest here is http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/rotatingEM.pdf.

Comment: @honeste_vivere can you help me calculate the nonzero components of stress-energy tensor in cylindrical coordinates?